# Running Ordered tests using MS-TEST throws error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, mstest, ordered-test

I started using Ordered tests recently in VS 2010. I have created a folder under my test-suite and dragged the tests (required tests in a flow) from test list editor to the ordered test list. I am able to run the ordered test from VS successfully. But when I run the ordered test using MSTest, ordered test gets error (all of its tests gets not executed). When I opened the Ordered test file in notepad, I see everything properly configured like storage path as shown below

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OrderedTest name="MyOrderedTest" storage="OrderedTests\MyOrderedTest.orderedtest" id="afadbaf6-7915-426d-932c-788fc27c7a8f" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <TestLinks>
    <TestLink id="c2367ab7-ab71-bdaf-d039-4d55ea87e962" name="TestOne" storage="TestSuiteName.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <TestLink id="cc156aeb-ed8e-12d6-c9ad-24fadc2ca54b" name="TestTwo" storage="TestSuiteName.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    <TestLink id="caa09202-b582-e53c-cae9-7fe8b402b4a2" name="TestThree" storage="TestSuiteName.dll" type="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestElement, Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Tips.UnitTest.ObjectModel, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </TestLinks>
</OrderedTest>*
```

[image: Test run error]
When I ran a single test 'TestOne' using MSTest, it runs successfully.
Is there anyother thing that I need to configure/change??

Thanks in Advance.
Sham_

Answer (score 1):

Did I understand you correctly: you have stored your ordered test in a sub-folder?

If so, just move your ordered test in to the root folder (do not use a sub-folder for storing them).

I had been facing the same problem using *ordered tests* for test automation. When running them from *Microsoft Test Manager* I got the error

`"Cannot find the test ‘XXX’ with storage ‘..\bin\debug\YYY.dll"`

According to this message *Test Agent* (the component that runs the tests) is looking for them in the root folder and not in a sub-folder I've stored them in.
Moving the *ordered tests* to the root folder of my solution solved the problem.

It seems to be a bug.

**PS:** You can check in the *Output* window why the tests were not executed.

Answer (score 1):

Even with 2012 version this issue exists .  Moving the ordered test to root folder solved the issue for me as well.